# How to know if all results are wrong in a javascript for statement

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this simple loop:

```
for (i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
    if (menuitem[i].href == window.location) {
        menuitem[i].className = "current"
    } else {
        if (menuitem[i].nodeType !== 3) {
            menuitem[1].className = "current";
        }
    };
```

how could I replace the else statement by "If all results of menuitem[i] are false"? because now for each single one that is false the else statement gets executed and I want to only execute it when the entire loop is false.

I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks for your help guys

Comment: What do you mean by "if all results of menuItem[i] are false"?  Do you literally mean if the whole array is empty or contains all false values?

Comment: if menuitem[i].href == window.location is false for all menuitems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see if the whole array contains false values, you would do this:

```
var found = false;
for (i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
    if (menuitem[i]) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found) {
    // some truthy value was found in the array
} else {
    // no truthy values found in the array
}
```

To see if the whole array fails your condition, you can do this:

```
var found = false;
for (i = 0; i < menuitem.length; i += 1) {
    if (menuitem[i].href == window.location) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (!found) {
    // no items in the array met your condition 
} else {
    // at least one item in the array met your condition
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the additional dependency, you could use [_.js's](http://underscorejs.org/#any) `_.any`. (You could also just copy the method from the source.)

Comment: How do you know the OP knows about Underscore.js?